# Procedure is having some issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a procedure test

```
alter Procedure [dbo].[test]
(
@Branch nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT        res.f_Employee_Id AS Employee_Id, emp.f_Employee_Name, q.f_Question AS Question, ISNULL(ans.f_Name, res.f_Answer) AS Answer, CONVERT(nvarchar, res.f_Created_Date, 103) AS Feedback_Date, 
                     emp.f_Grade AS Grade, emp.f_Branch_DESC AS Branch
FROM            T_PAF_EmployeeResult AS res WITH (nolock) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     t_PAF_FeedbackAns_Master AS ans WITH (nolock) ON res.f_Answer = ans.f_Code INNER JOIN
                     t_PAF_FeedbackQues_Master AS q WITH (nolock) ON res.f_Question_Id = q.f_Uid INNER JOIN
                     T_PAF_EmployeeList_2017 AS emp WITH (nolock) ON emp.f_Employee_ID = res.f_Employee_Id
WHERE        

((@Branch = emp.f_Branch_DESC) OR
                     (@Branch IS NULL)) and f_Company_Id=1031


ORDER BY Employee_Id, res.f_Question_Id
END
```

**exec test 'Head Office'**

**Output**

```
Employee_Id f_Employee_Name     Question                                                            Answer          Feedback_Date   Grade   Branch  

1234        XYZ         My appraiser is aware of all the work i am involved in.                                     Strongly Disagree   29/06/2017  L10 C   HEAD OFFICE  

1234        XYZ         My appraiser tries to understand my point of view when he or she discusses problems or work  with me .              Disagree        29/06/2017  L10 C   HEAD OFFICE  

1234        XYZ         My appraiser has good understanding of my strengths and weaknesses.                             Neutral         29/06/2017  L10 C   HEAD OFFICE  

1234        XYZ         My appraiser gives me clear direction for the work that i am expected to do.                            Agree           29/06/2017  L10 C   HEAD OFFICE  

1234        XYZ         My appraiser provides me with necessary support to resolve issues at work (team related/client related/schedule related etc).   Strongly Agree      29/06/2017  L10 C   HEAD OFFICE
```

alter

```
alter Procedure [dbo].[test]
(
@Branch nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT        res.f_Employee_Id AS Employee_Id, emp.f_Employee_Name, q.f_Question AS Question, ISNULL(ans.f_Name, res.f_Answer) AS Answer, CONVERT(nvarchar, res.f_Created_Date, 103) AS Feedback_Date, 
                     emp.f_Grade AS Grade, emp.f_Branch_DESC AS Branch
FROM            T_PAF_EmployeeResult AS res WITH (nolock) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     t_PAF_FeedbackAns_Master AS ans WITH (nolock) ON   res.f_Answer = ans.f_Code INNER JOIN
                     t_PAF_FeedbackQues_Master AS q WITH (nolock) ON res.f_Question_Id = q.f_Uid INNER JOIN
                     T_PAF_EmployeeList_2017 AS emp WITH (nolock) ON emp.f_Employee_ID = res.f_Employee_Id

WHERE        

        ((@Branch = emp.f_Branch_DESC) OR
                     (@Branch IS NULL)) and f_Company_Id=1031
        and
        (
            ans.f_Name in ('Agree','Disagree') or res.f_Answer in ('Agree','Disagree')
        )


ORDER BY Employee_Id, res.f_Question_Id
END
```

**exec test 'Head Office'**

Output is Blank

When i add this code in my procedure it is coming blank:

```
and
    (
        ans.f_Name in ('Agree','Disagree') or res.f_Answer in    ('Agree','Disagree')
    )
```

Comment: Maybe there are leading blanks in columns f_Name or f_Answer? Could you check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your condition

```
and 
( 
      ISNULL(ans.f_Name, res.f_Answer) like '%Agree%'
)
```

Comment: It is still blank

Comment: for your previous code that is without " and " clause, is there any data for " Answer " column contains 'Agree' or 'Disagree' value ?

Comment: Yes I uploaded the answer as well

Comment: Ok its working now, Can you explain me why its working with like

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I think `IN` operator handles `NULL` properly but `NOT IN` has problems with them.
I can't force SQLFiddle to work, so I will past example here:
`DECLARE @tab TABLE (col varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES ('aa '), (' aa'), ('aa'), (NULL)

SELECT 'a' WHERE 'a' NOT IN (SELECT * FROM @tab);
SELECT 'a' WHERE 'aa' IN (SELECT * FROM @tab);

DELETE FROM @tab WHERE col IS NULL;

SELECT 'a' WHERE 'a' NOT IN (SELECT * FROM @tab);
SELECT 'a' WHERE 'aa' IN (SELECT * FROM @tab);`
As you can see, `IN` had no problems with `NULL` values, but `NOT IN` returned nothing.

Comment: @Rokuto Yes, you are correct. `NOT IN` is causing troubles because it translates to WHERE A <> B AND A <> C, and AND definitely can't be true with NULL.